# Compute the integral $ \int_C \frac{dz}{z}$, where $C$ is the square

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the integral $ \int_C \frac{dz}{z}$, where $C$ is the square described in the positive sense with sides parallel to the axes and of lengths $2a$ and having its centre at the origin.

**Answer:**

I can solve the problem with alternate method. But I need to understand the method explained below:

I got the answer in a book as follows:

[image]

From the graph, we have

$z=-ai+t$ along $AB$;

$z=a+it$ along $BC$;

$z=t+ia$ along $CD$;

$z=-a+it$ along $DA$;

where $t$ is scalar.

My question-

$ \text{How does we get the above equations from the graph?}$

The line $AB$ is the line segment joining $A=(-a,-a)$ and $B=(a,-a)$,

which is given by

$\frac{x+a}{y+a}=\frac{2a}{0} \\ \Rightarrow  y=-a $.

But how do we get $ z=-ai+t$, where $t$ is scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Remember the complex numbers are identified with the plane $\mathbb R^2$ as follows: $$z=x+iy$$ corresponds to the point $$(x,y)$$ in the plane.

Under this identification,  you will see that the two descriptions are of the same line.  Namely, $y=-a$ is the line $z=-ai+t$, in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line $AB$. The imaginary part is constant $-a$ there. What is changing along the line is the real part, it changes from $-a$ to $a$. Hence the parametrization is $z=t-ai$ when $t\in[-a,a]$.

Comment: how the parametrization   is $ z=t-ai, \ \ -a \leq t \leq a$?. How to the parametrization in complex anlysis?

Comment: Think of parametrization as the set of all points on the line. And as I explained the set of points is $\{t-ai:t\in[-a,a]\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following parametrization which connect two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ with a segment between them:
$$z(t)=(1-t)z_1+tz_2$$
where $0\leq t\leq 1$. This parametrization has direction from $z_1$ to $z_2$. For instance with $A:\ z_1=-a-ai$ and $B:\ z_2=a-ai$ we have
$$z(t)=(2t-1)a-ai$$
where $0\leq t\leq 1$.

Comment: But that does not match the equation of $AB$ given above

Comment: The domain of parameter in parametrization is important. In yours $-a<t<a$ right?

Comment: In addition you may write it as $-ai+at$ where $-1\leq t\leq 1$

Comment: yes. Ok I understand